# I am unable to install a package

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, ros

I want to install a package on Ubuntu 16.04, but receive an error when performing this command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libavcodec-dev libsdl1.2-dev xsltproc libbullet-dev libsdl1.2-dev libgoogle-glog-dev protobuf-compiler python-wstool

E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?
```

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Welcome! if you're using Ubuntu 16.04, please correct the question tag from 14.04. Also, a reminder: Ubuntu 16.04 is to be 'End of Life' any moment soon this week., and will not receive any further updates, support, or package availability from existing repositories. If possible, try to upgrade to version 18.04 maybe? This might also solve some of your problems as well.

Comment: @David the initial EOL of *standard support* for 16.04 was 5 years from release; or 21-April-2016 (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2016/04/21/ubuntu-16-04-lts-xenial-xerus-released/) ...   various past releases have been supported until the 5 year date (21-April) or been stretched till end of month, or a thursday between the date & end-of-month.. ESM starts 30-April yes (last date an official notice mentioned), but I'd not expect any fixed/upgraded packages for *xenial* from 22-April-2021 (but they've occurred before..)

Comment: https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/  @David ^